# Unable to use method of a class in different class-missing 2 required positional arguments

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary

I have two python classes:- One class(CloudLink) is responsible for sending JSON events to the app and another(ReadData) is responsible for building the JSON data.
The ReadData class will be using the CloudLink methods to send the JSON data to the App. But I'm getting error `_buildJSONdata() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Data'`.
**ReadData class**

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import functools
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
from  cosmosconnect import azurecosmos



class ReadData:

    @exception(logger)
    def __init__(self):

        self.spark_session = (
            SparkSession.builder
            .appName("readData")
            .getOrCreate()
        )


        mssparkutils.fs.unmount('/mnt/test')
        logger.info("Drive unmounted") 
        mssparkutils.fs.mount(
            'abfss://abc@transl.dfs.core.windows.net/',  
            '/mnt/test',  
            {'linkedService': "linkCosmos"}
        )

        logger.info("Mounted Successfully") 
        self.input_directory = (f"synfs:/{mssparkutils.env.getJobId()}/mnt/test/input_path"
        )
        self.output_directory = (f"synfs:/{mssparkutils.env.getJobId()}/mnt/test/output_path"
        )
   
    '''
    Reading the schema from csv file
    '''
    @exception(logger)
    def readConfig(self):
        try:
            
            logger.info(f"Reading the Config present in {self.input_directory} ")
            dfConfig = self.spark_session.read.option("multiline","true") \
                           .json(self.input_directory)
            #for f in dfConfig.select("Entity","Query","Business_Rule").collect():
            dfConfig=dfConfig.select(explode('Input').alias('Input_Data'))\
                 .select('Input_Data.Validation_Type','Input_Data.Entity','Input_Data.Query','Input_Data.Business_Rule')
            for f in dfConfig.rdd.toLocalIterator():
            #for index, f in dfConfig.toPandas().iterrows():
                self.Validation_Type=f[0]
                self.container=f[1]
                self.query=f[2]
                self.rule=f[3]               
                self.readCosmos(self)
        except:
            raise ValueError("")

    @exception(logger)
    def readCosmos(self,*params):
        #from  cosmosconnect import azurecosmos
        #a=[]
        linkedService='fg'
        df=azurecosmos.cosmosConnect(linkedService,self.query,self.container)
        df.cache()
        if len(df.head(1)) >0:
           outputpath=self.output_directory+'/'+self.container
           df.coalesce(1).write.mode('overwrite').parquet(outputpath)
           Status="Validation Failure"
           Data= {"Validation_Type":[],"Status":[],"Container":[],"Business_Rule":[]}
           Data["Validation_Type"].append(self.Validation_Type)
           Data["Status"].append(Status)
           Data["Container"].append(self.container)
           Data["Business_Rule"].append(self.rule)
           CloudLink._buildJSONdata(Data)
        



if __name__ == "__main__":
   p = ReadData()
   p.readConfig()
```

**CloudLink class**

```
import json
import datetime
import hashlib
import json
import sys
import traceback
 
import adal
import requests
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry
import logging
from functools import wraps
import sys
def create_logger(): 
      
    #create a logger object
    #logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
      
    logfile = logging.FileHandler('exc_logger.log')
    #logfile = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
      
    fmt = '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
    formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt)
      
    logfile.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(logfile)
      
    return logger


   
  
logger = create_logger()
  
   
  
def exception(logger):

    def decorator(func):
          
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
              
            try:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
              
            except:
                issue = "exception in "+func.__name__+"\n"
                issue = issue+"-------------------------\
                ------------------------------------------------\n"
                logger.exception(issue)
            raise
               
          
        return wrapper
    return decorator
    
class CloudLink(object):
    _token = None
    _instance = None
    http = None
    cloudclient = TokenLibrary.getSecret("xxxx", "rtrt")
    clientid = TokenLibrary.getSecret("xxxx", "tyty")
    clientcredentials = TokenLibrary.getSecret("xxxx", "abcabc")
    authority_url = TokenLibrary.getSecret("xxxx", "abab")
    cloudtest = TokenLibrary.getSecret("xxxx", "yyyy")

    @staticmethod
    def getInstance():

        if not CloudLink._instance:
            CloudLink._instance = CloudLink()

        return CloudLink._instance

    def __init__(self):

        retry_strategy = Retry(
            total=3,
            backoff_factor=0,
            status_forcelist=[429, 500, 502, 503, 504],
            allowed_methods=["HEAD", "GET", "OPTIONS"],
        )
        adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry_strategy)
        self.http = requests.Session()
        self.http.mount("https://", adapter)
        self.http.mount("http://", adapter)
        print("Inside init")

    def parseJSON(self, t):
        try:
            eventData = json.loads(t)
            logger.info(f"Sending {eventData} to cloud")
            self.sendToCloud(eventData)
        except ValueError as e:
            print("Error: %s Please validate JSON in https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/"% e)
            return None  # or: raise

    def sendToCloud(self, eventData):
        cloudData = {"eventData": eventData, "metadata": self._buildMetadata()}
        logger.info(f"Raising alert with data=({cloudData}")
        response = self.http.post(
            self.cloudtest, headers=self._buildHeaders(), json=cloudData
        )
        logger.info(f"cloud alert response={response}")
        if response.status_code == 202 or response.status_code == 200:
            logger.info("Mail sent to Cloud")
        else:
            raise Exception(f"Cloud reporting failed with Error {response}")

    def _buildJSONdata(self,Data):
        if len(Data) == 0:
            raise Exception("JSON is empty")
        else:
            t = json.dumps(self.Data)
            self.parseJSON(t)

    def _buildMetadata(self):
        return {
            "messageType": "Send Email",
            "messageVersion": "0.0.1",
            "sender": "Send Email",
          }

    def _buildHeaders(self):
        self._refreshADToken()

        headers = {
            "Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(self._token["accessToken"]),
            "Content-type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "text/plain",
        }
        return headers

    def _refreshADToken(self):
        def shouldRenew(token):
            """Returns True if the token should be renewed"""

            expiresOn = datetime.datetime.strptime(
                token["expiresOn"], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"
            )
            now = datetime.datetime.now()
            return (expiresOn - now) < datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)

        if not self._token or shouldRenew(self._token):
            logger.info("Renewing credentials for Alerting")
            result = None

            try:
                context = adal.AuthenticationContext(CloudLink.authority_url)
                result = context.acquire_token_with_client_credentials(CloudLink.cloudclient, CloudLink.clientid,CloudLink.clientcredentials)
            except Exception as e:
                error = "Failed to renew client credentials."
                logger.info(error)
                raise

            if result and "accessToken" in result:
                self._token = result
            else:
                logger.error(
                    "Failed to acquire bearer token. accessToken not found in result object on renewing credentials."
                )
                raise Exception("Could not acquire a bearer token")
```

Comment: Take a look at the last two lines of `readCosmos()`. The first of these is calling `_buildJSONdata()` with no arguments and the second one is trying to call the method from the return value of the first (`None`).

Comment: @DennisWilliamson  I have updated those last two lines and now I m getting error-AttributeError: 'ReadData' object has no attribute 'Data'

Comment: Try removing the parentheses from `apiAlert = CloudLink()`. Why are you using that variable anyway? Why not just do `CloudLink._buildJSONdata(Data)` without the assignment?

Comment: @DennisWilliamson I have changed it to CloudLink._buildJSONdata(Data) and now I m getting the error-_buildJSONdata() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Data'

Comment: You're supplying `Data` but you're missing `Data` hmmmm...I wonder what's wrong.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson I didn't got your point.Since I am already supply the data in both ways as you mentioned

Comment: Any pointers @DennisWilliamson?